# scheme function returns step values but doesnt append an empty list to it

Tags: scheme

I need to write a scheme function `(iterator (start step end))` which returns a function which when repeatedly called returns the numbers in the sequence `(range (start step end))`. When the sequence is exhausted the returned function should return `()`.
Example: `(define next (iterator '(0 2 7)))`, `(begin (next) (next) (next) (next) (next))` => `0, 2, 4, 6, ()`

```
; lab 1

(define (range L)
  (let ((start (car L))
        (step (car (cdr L)))
        (end (car (cdr (cdr L)))))
    (if (> start end)
        cons '()
        (cons start (range (list (+ start step) step end))))))
```

when I call `range '(0 2 7)` i get `(0 2 4 6)` however i need to get `(0 2 4 6) ()`

why isn't the `cons '()` appending to the list i have

Comment: Protip: Learn to format and indent scheme code.

Comment: You probably just want `'()` (or maybe `'(())`)

Comment: I want range '(0 2 7) to return 0 2 4 6 '()

Comment: Is my cons '() the issue?

Comment: if I do range '(7 2 0) i do get '() however if the range does work then the empty list never appaends to (0 2 4 6) for example

Comment: Your text and code does not match up.

Comment: From the text part of the question, it seems to want an iterator, so just creating a list in `range` is wrong IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the `range` procedure by passing three *parameters*, not a list of parameters. Apart from some minor syntax errors you're on the right track:

```
(define (range start step end)
  (if (> start end)
      '()
      (cons start
            (range (+ start step) step end))))
```

For example:

```
(range 0 2 7)
=> '(0 2 4 6)
```

Notice that the list already ends in a `'()` (which is not displayed). If you want another `'()` apart from the results, try this:

```
(list (range 0 2 7) '())
=> '((0 2 4 6) ())
```

Comment: okay thanks what does cons '() '() really do then. does it create a list of two empty lists?

Comment: @LokiKira No, `(cons '() '())` creates a list with one item, an empty list.

Comment: How do you create two empty lists then?

Comment: @LokiKira `(list '() '())`

Comment: or `(cons '() (cons '() '()))`.

Answer (score 1):

As @leppie points out, the accepted solution does not match your text. I would have thought of the following:

```
(define (iterator start step end)
  (lambda ()
    (if (>= start end) 
        '()
        (begin0
          start
          (set! start (+ start step))))))
```

testing:

```
(define i (iterator 0 2 7))
(i)
=> 0
(i)
=> 2
(i)
=> 4
(i)
=> 6
(i)
=> '()
(i)
=> '()
```

Note that I use Racket's `begin0` form. If your Scheme doesn't have it, you can change to the following:

```
(define (iterator start step end)
  (lambda ()
    (if (>= start end) 
        '()
        (let ((res start))
          (set! start (+ start step))
          res))))
```

Comment: I love `begin0` and it can easily be defined in Scheme: `(define-syntax begin0 (syntax-rules () ((_ x) x) ((_ x y ...) (let ((tmp x)) y ... tmp))))`